# Как сделать зависимые ChoiceBox или ComboBox между собой, отображение параметров по умолчанию в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, scene-builder

Решил сделать пару программок себе, в программировании и в Java я человек новый. Есть у меня две трудности.
В JavaFX сделал 4 ChoiceBox(Через SceneBuilder) они представляют из себя выпадающие списки 4-х разных типов оборудования с разным количеством выбора строк(оборудования входящего в этот тип). Как реализовать зависимость одного выпадающего списка от другого, то есть выбрал в первом списке нужную строку и в следующе списке был выбор исходя из того, что выбрано в предыдущем. Вторая проблема у меня возникла в том, что бы когда я в первом выпадающем списке выбрал нужную строку в остальных сбросился выбор по умолчанию, как бы очистились, что бы не было видно то, что я до этого выбирал.

Comment: С наступающим Новым годом!  Ради бога, перечитайте и конкретизируйте свой вопрос :)

Comment: Попробовал переформулировать)

Comment: Вот простой пример, как выбор ChoiceBox изменяет UI, но у вас будет случай чуть посложнее, но принцип тот же. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/example-to-set-action-listeners-behavior-to-a-choicebox-in-javafx